# Changing input field based on other input field?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to have the datalist from "Serienummer" change based on what "Product" is chosen.

```
<td>Product</td>
              <td>
                <Select name="ProductID" placeholder="Productnaam" required>
                  <?php
                  $query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM HW_Serial WHERE Prefix = '$prefix'";
                  $result2 = mssql_query($query2);
                  $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result2);
                  while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result2))
                  {
                    $DisProductID=$row["ProductID"];
                    $query3 = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = '$DisProductID' order by ProductName";
                    $result3 = mssql_query($query3);
                    $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result3);
                    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result3))
                    {
                      $xProductID=$row["ProductID"];
                      $xProductName=$row["ProductName"];
                      if ($ProductID == $xProductID) {
                        echo "<OPTION value =\"$xProductID\">$xProductName</OPTION>";
                      } else {
                        echo "<OPTION value =\"$xProductID\">$xProductName</OPTION>";
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  ?>
                </select>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Serienummer</td>
                <td>
                  <input list="devicesn" name="devicesn" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Serienummer" required>
                  <datalist id="devicesn">
                    <?php
                    $query2 = "SELECT devicesn FROM HW_Serial WHERE ProductID = '$ProductID' order by devicesn";
                    $result2 = mssql_query($query2);
                    $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result2);
                    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                      $xdevicesn=$row["devicesn"];
                      if ($devicesn == $xdevicesn) {
                        echo "<OPTION value =\"$xdevicesn\">$xdevicesn</OPTION>";
                      } else {
                        echo "<OPTION value =\"$xdevicesn\">$xdevicesn</OPTION>";
                      }
                    }
                    ?>
```

My guess is that this has to be done by use of JavaScript but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to current page with parameter when `<select>` changed. And receive the parameter in your php code in **datalist** section.

For example:

```
<select name="ProductID" placeholder="Productnaam" required onchange="location.href='?product' + this.value">...</select>
```

Then I just say sorry, I do not know how to receive url parameters like `yourpage?p=project` in PHP.